# Set system property with spEL arithmetic

Tags: spring, spring-el

The following property is configured in a properties file:
`readTimeout=10`. I want to use it to set the system property `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout`, but first multiply it by 1000 (to convert to ms.)
I tried the following, which does not work:

```
<bean id="systemPrereqs"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" value="#{@systemProperties}" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout"
                value="#{T(java.lang.Integer).valueOf('${readTimeout}')*1000}" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

No `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` system property gets created.

However, if I use the following expression:
`#{'${readTimeout}'*1000}` then it is evaluated, and `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` system property is created, but with 101010.... (a thousand repetitions).

Seems that Spring has a problem with type conversion using `T(java.lang.Integer).valueOf`. Maybe because the spEL expression is not supported in util:properties/map definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `'${readTimeout}'`, `readTimeout` will work fine:

```
<entry key="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout" value="#{new Integer(readTimeout) * 1000}" />
```

Comment: trying your suggestion, i get the following: EL1008E:(pos 12): Property or field 'readTimeout' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?

Comment: @danieln Maybe you have another problem in some other place? I don't know if it is related to `readTimeout`,  because it should be now properly calculated.